# How do I maintain round corners on border of automatic image slider

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using an automatic image slider by [Soh Tanaka](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/automatic-image-slider-w-css-jquery/) in which on my images I have specified round corners using css3 border-radius.

[image: image when static]

The problem I am having is that when the images animate between one another the appearance is that of a rectangular image because the radial corners are moving with each image within the confines of the 'window' wrapper/mask.

[image: image when in transition]

I have considered using artifical corners on the 'window' wrapper using div strips however because I have a transparent background outside of the slider this isn't an option.

Comment: Can you use `border-radius` on the image elements at all? Or wrap each image in a container `div`, applying `border-radius` to *that*?

Comment: David, have tried this, unfortunately it still has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to go a little more old-school and use images for your rounded corners.  As long as you create the images with transparent backgrounds, you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: As mentioned, I can't use images for the rounded corners because the slider sits within a container which has a transparent background.

Comment: @Mike, even more old school: round the corners of your slide show images (not with css).

Comment: @Nimrod I have tried that also but the outcome is still the same as the images lye on top of a transparent div, so if i trim the corners of the image to give a rounded appearance it makes no difference

Comment: @Mike, I'm not understanding your transparency issue.  It seems like Mike's solution would work find if you [use an image with a transparent background](http://www.ehow.com/how_2029201_png-photoshop.html).

Comment: @muirbot Because whether I use a transparent image with rounded corners or set border radius on the images, when the image slides to the next image it passes out of the confines of the window div (effectively a mask) which has squares edges.